# Why is UISearchBar tableview index path always returning objectAtIndex:0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a tableview that loads with an array called self.annotationToSort and uses a UISearchBar to search for objects in the tableview and updates the results.  If an item in the tableview is selected, a detail view is displayed with the corresponding index path's information.

The issue Im having is that when the search bar is used, i get the 2 resulting items in the search, the values in the cells are displayed correctly, but then I click on result B, I get object A passed to the detail view controller.  If I click on A, I also get A.

Here is the relevant code:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if ([self.annotationsToSort count] == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [filteredResultsArray count];
    } else {
        return [self.annotationsToSort count];
    }
}

#pragma mark Content Filtering
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    [self.filteredResultsArray removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.name contains[c] %@) OR (SELF.ciudad contains[c] %@)", searchText,searchText];
    [self.filteredResultsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.annotationsToSort filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]] retain];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    tableType = @"FILTER";
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
    return YES;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    NSLog(@"indexpath selected %@", indexPath);

    //Check if using normal or search array
    if ([tableType isEqualToString:@"FILTER"]) {
        MyLocation *sendingLocation = [self.filteredResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationViewController.receivedLocation = sendingLocation;
        NSLog(@"indexpath selected filter %@", indexPath);
    } else {
        MyLocation *sendingLocation = [self.annotationsToSort objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationViewController.receivedLocation = sendingLocation;
        NSLog(@"indexpath selected regular %@", indexPath);
    }
}
```

I can see the index path being logged as null when the tableview is being filtered.  It always returns objectAtIndex:0.

Comment: What does the `NSLog(@"indexpath selected %@", indexPath);` output?

Comment: @Wain I just edited my question.  When in filter mode, it logs null!  But the tableview still displays all the correctly filtered results.

Comment: Holy nested nesting batman.  As soon as I run into a problem I don't understand, one of the first steps (certainly before posting a question to StackOverflow) is rewriting the code into something readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];`, because sometimes you will be asking the wrong table view and it will return nil (which, when accessed results on a row number of zero).

Instead, check if you are filtered and ask the appropriate table view for the index.

Comment: Well isn't that what the if/else is doing? I check for the filter, it works because I do enter that first if-block.  It logs the array with both results & since Im in the filter, I use self.filteredResultsArray instead of using the other array.  What am I not understanding? thx

Comment: You need to get the index path inside the if, from the appropriate table.

Comment: ok that must be what im missing. I just moved the index path getter into each if-block but I only have one tableview. Isn't it just updating the data in the same tableview?

Comment: self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView

Comment: Gr8!  I got it by Jumping To Definition of the UISearchDisplayController...thx!